# issue with implementation of minimax algorithm for multi-agent pacman with multple min layers

Tags: algorithm, recursion, artificial-intelligence, minimax, pacman

The following is the code snippet of minimax algorithm for multi-agent pacman where there are multiple ghosts(min players).

```
def min_max(self, gamestate, current_depth, min_count):
    if current_depth == 1:
         return (self.evaluationFunction(gamestate),None)
# if max node
    if min_count == 0:
        min_count = gamestate.getNumAgents() - 1
        legal_actions = gamestate.getLegalActions(0)
        max_list = []
        for action in legal_actions:
            max_list.append((self.min_max(gamestate.generateSuccessor(0, action), current_depth - 1, min_count), action))
        return max(max_list, key = itemgetter(0))
# if min nodes...
    else:
        legal_actions = gamestate.getLegalActions(min_count)
        min_list = []
        for action in legal_actions:
            min_list.append((self.min_max(gamestate.generateSuccessor(min_count, action),current_depth - 1, min_count - 1), action))
            print(current_depth,min_count)
        return min(min_list, key = itemgetter(0))

pacman_move = self.min_max(gameState, self.depth * (no_of_ghosts + 1) + 1, 0)[1]
```

But I'm getting the following error: 
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear, so try to figure out why `min` gets passed an empty sequence. For debugging, add a `print min_list` just before the call to `min`. Since `min_list` gets appended to in a for-loop that iterates over `legal_actions`, you probably want to add some debug prints of that as well, and try to understand why it is empty, while you assumed it to be non-empty. Work backwards from there, until you understand the problem.

Comment: The issue may be that you run into the endState before depth reaches 1. I am currently working on exactly the same problem and i would like to have a chat with you about this code. If you are interested let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any legal moves at min-step - and that's why `min_list` is empty.

```
>>> min([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

Thus handle the case of:

```
if not legal_actions:
    # pass? win? lose?
```

before doing `min()`

Comment: well, I was not expecting min to be empty. Not sure where I'm going wrong

Comment: it could be that 1 ghost is blocked if this evaluates a single one, or then you just calculate legal moves incorrectly..